# 'Undefined reference' despite class being linked properly

Tags: gcc, linker-errors

I have the following problem - I'm trying a sort of bastardized build of the poco library for C++ (ie, using a premake-generated makefile instead of the poco makefile because I'm building on windows without msvc)

I've actually managed to get all the libraries built into .a files. The problem arises when I try to actually use classes - and then gcc swears up and down that it can't find the reference. This despite the fact that I have checked the libraries with `ar -t`  and seen that the classes in question do indeed exist there.

In general, what could be the problem? I have a library that at least claims to have the requisite .o files, yet the references are still undefined.

For example, I have an undefined reference to `Poco::XML::InputSource::InputSource(std::istream&)`, yet "InputSource.o" is in the linked library, and the requisite ctor is in the header file.

Comment: Yes. I know this because it does find the library names.

Comment: Does the appropriate linker flag, i. e. "gcc -lSomething" present in the Makefile?

Comment: This hasn't reached the point of a makefile yet :)

But yes, gcc indeed has the appropriate linker flag. In this case, -lPocoXMLmtd. Changing anything after the l gives me an error of not finding the library - unsurprisingly. The library name is correct.

Comment: Does `nm -C InputSource.o` list the symbol you expect?